# NoMethodError in PostsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

I am having trouble creating and updating posts in rails 4. I get the error

NoMethodError in PostsController#update
undefined method `title' for #

Here's my posts controller.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def tags
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag], :any => true).order('created_at DESC')
end
# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
  @latest_posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end

# GET /posts/new
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @latest_posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
  @latest_posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /posts/1
# PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :content, :slug, :tag_list, :topic_list, :image,        :category)
  end
end
```

I have looked all over and it seems that these errors all come from something simple like a typo or making your params private, but I just don't see it here. The error is saying it is from the if @post.update(post_params) line in the update action.

Comment: I don't see any reference to title on my phone. Is it possible you changed from title to name? Perhaps title is still in your post form.

Comment: I have no idea how it happened but I most certainly did have validates presence of title in my post model. Totally helped me out!